# Why does Doxygen generate documentation for instantiated template-types that are only used privately?

Tags: c++, templates, doxygen

I'm trying to figure out why Doxygen is cluttering up the output it generates for me with descriptions of specific template-instantiations -- even when those particular instantiations are never visible in any of my library's public API.  (Specifically, they are only used in private member-variables)

Is this a bug in Doxygen, or am I just missing some reasoning for why this documentation is relevant?  And if it's the latter, is there any setting I might change that would remove these classes from my Doxygen output?

Here's a trivial header-file that can be used to reproduce the fault:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

/** An example templated class */
template<typename T> class MyTemplatedClass
{
public:
   /** Constructor */
   MyTemplatedClass() {/* empty */}

private:
   T _t;
};

/** A templated subclass of the example templated class */
template<typename T> class MyTemplatedSubclass : public MyTemplatedClass<T>
{
public:
   /** Constructor */
   MyTemplatedSubclass() {/* empty */}

private:
   T _t;
};

/** Some other class */
class SomeOtherClass
{
public:
   SomeOtherClass() {/* empty */}

private:
   MyTemplatedSubclass<int> _mtci;    // note these are not visible to calling code!
   MyTemplatedSubclass<float> _mtcf;
};

#endif
```

My .dox file for this test is very close to the default-generated one; here is the output of `doxygen -x test.dox` showing the diffs relative to the default:

```
Jeremys-Mac-mini-2:crap jaf$ doxygen -x ./test.dox
# Difference with default Doxyfile 1.9.6 (4586b5cfaa3d46d51f6a51882951d15644c49edf)
PROJECT_NAME           = TEST
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = .
ABBREVIATE_BRIEF       = NO
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = YES
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = YES
TAB_SIZE               = 8
TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = YES
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = YES
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = YES
WARN_AS_ERROR          = YES
INPUT                  = .
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.h
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       =
SOURCE_BROWSER         = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES
REFERENCES_RELATION    = YES
HTML_TIMESTAMP         = YES
MATHJAX_RELPATH        = http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest
LATEX_CMD_NAME         = latex
PDF_HYPERLINKS         = NO
USE_PDFLATEX           = NO
GENERATE_RTF           = YES
GENERATE_MAN           = YES
GENERATE_XML           = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           = .
GENERATE_TAGFILE       = test.tag
HAVE_DOT               = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = NO
```

Annotated screenshots are below, with the unexpected output outlined in red:

[image: screenshots from Doxygen 1.9.6]

Comment: Got it, I missed it.

Comment: Also, is it actually generating separate documentation pages for those types, or do they all link to the same place?

Comment: They all link to the same page.

Comment: You use doxygen 1.9.3 but what happens when you use the current doxygen version (1.9.6)? Please post your doxygen settings as a difference agaist the defaults (i.e. the output of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`) and not a link to a non persistent page.

Comment: I think that it is because the variables are private, but the specializations are still public. It is of course, in general, dubious whether or not specializations should be shown at all. Maybe best to create an issue in the doxygen issue tracker at GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @albert, I have updated the question.  Updating to 1.9.6 did not seem to significantly change the behavior.

Comment: @albert It looks like this issue might already be tracked in Doxygen's Github page as https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/4796 ... I'm not 100% sure it's the same thing, but it looks similar.  I can file a new case if that would be helpful and not just a duplicate.

Comment: Indeed looks quite similar, best is to add a comment with your case (copy the data of the stack overflow question).